# React Router: Create header for specific routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Please have a look at the below routes.

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  Home, 
  Contact, 
  Jobs, 
  Careers, 
  Dashboard, 
  Group
} from '../container'

// ?
const Header = () => {
  return (<div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}> Test Custom header </div>)
}

// 
const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
      <Route exact path='/contactus' component={ Contact }></Route>
      <Route exact path='/jobs' component={ Jobs } />
      <Route exact path='/careers' component={ Careers } />
    
      {/** header */}
      {/** Render Header component (only once) only for the dashboard and group component  */}
      <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={ Dashboard } />
      <Route exact path='/group' component={ Group } />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

export default Routes
```

Here, **I want to add a common header (Header component) only for the /dashboard and /group route and this header component should be rendered only once**. I tried some approaches:

- Create HOC for these two routes and render Header component but in this case, the Header component will render twice when the user switches between the two routes.
- If I conditionally render the header only for these two routes, In this also Header rendering problem will not be resolved.

Could you please suggest a good approach for this case?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is to add a Route for each header and pass an array of paths to path on the routes where you want to show certain header.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path=["/dashboard", "/group"] component={Header} /> 
  <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  <Route exact path="/group" component={Group} />
  ...other Routes
</Switch>
```

Hope this works and helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) but I think, in this case, the header component will render twice when the user changes the routes (from /dashboard to / group or /group to /dashboard)

Comment: Ah I see, you want to minimize the renders of your header. Do you want your header to be aware of what route he is on? Im not sure if its possible to prevent a render for this purpose, because you always have to have some kind of logic which is based on a path or location state. If you have that logic in your header, you rerender everytime the history state changes. If you have that logic in your Switch and Routes, then they handle the rerender based on location state. Either way, you have to run a render based on state change. Why is it so bad to have the header render when you change route?

Comment: If you want to get very hacky, you could have some kind of function outside of your Components that listens to location changes and based on your logic will update the Headers props in order to show either the one header or the other. I have to say, extracting state/props logic outside of your App/Component scope can get very complicated and i dont know exactly how you could listen to location change outside of a component